# Retrieve all related objects (reverse foreign keys) efficiently with django

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
Car:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=80)

Driver:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='drivers')
```

Now I want to retrieve all of cars including related model driver data

```
cars = Car.objects.prefetch_related('drivers').all()
```

Now in my template I just want to print each car and the first driver information

```
{% for car in cars %}
  <tr>
    <td>car.name</td>
    <td>car.model</td>
    <td>car.drivers.first.name</td>
    <td>car.drivers.first.address</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this results in 2k+ queries for around 500 cards in my db and it takes a while to load. Am I doing something wrong, is there anyway to make this more efficient?

Comment: Using `.first` probably causes a new query to be processed for each `Car` object. Try using `car.drivers.all.1.name` and so on and let me know if this solves it. For an explanation as to why this happens: Django's QuerySet's `first` function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first) causes a new query to be sent to the DB, while `prefetch_related` caches the related objects in the related query's `.all()` results.

Comment: for `Foreign Key` relationships, I think you had better use `select_related` rather that `prefetch_related` which is good for `ManyToMany` relationships

Comment: @YotamOfek That worked perfectly, seems much better now.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I was going to but I thought select_related was specific to one to one only...

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov `select_related()` only ever fetches a single instance by using a join. `prefetch_related()` fetches multiple instances (in a separate query) and must be used in case of a many-to-many or a reverse foreign key relation. This case is a reverse foreign key relation.

Comment: you can not use select_related or prefetch_related in Car. because its a reverse many to one relation